# In CSS computed properties panel, the topmost style does not seem to overwrite the less specific style — how could that be?

Tags: css

A certain element in my HTML has a parent element with `font-size: 0`, but then it has its own CSS rules with `font-size: 1.9em`. I can verify this in Chrome’s `computed properties` panel. I can also see that the style with `font-size: 0` is crossed out, so it's overridden. And yet, to my great surprise, the resultant calculated `font-size` is still 0. How can this be possible?

*(The element does not have any inline styles, if anyone is wondering)*

[image]

Comment: CSS works by having global properties, which can be over-ridden later on in the document for specific elements or classes of elements; however without seeing your complete CSS specifcations, it would be difficult to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create parent element with a font size 0px every tags inside which has font-size specified in emphasis like 1.9em it will calculate 0*1.9 = 0px.

You may want to use root element font size (specified in the html tag)
`font-size:1.9rem;`

When the html tag has font size set for 10px it will produce 1.9*10=19px.

Comment: Oh, of course! Em gets redefined, and 0*1.9 equals 0. How stupid of me to forget that! Thank you!